# Skip Ansible task when running in check mode?

Tags: ansible

I'm writing an Ansible playbook and have a task which will always fail in check mode:

```
hosts: ...
tasks:
    - set_fact: filename="{{ansible_date_time.iso8601}}"
    - file: state=touch name={{filename}}
    - file: state=link src={{filename}} dest=latest
```

In check mode, the file will not be created so the `link` task will always fail.  Is there a way to mark such a task to be skipped when running in check mode?  Something like:

```
- file: state=link src={{filename}} dest=latest
  when: not check_mode
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Ansible 2.1 supports `ansible_check_mode` magic variable which is set to `True` in check mode ([official docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_checkmode.html#running-a-task-in-check-mode)). This means you will be able to do this:

```
- file:
    state: link
    src: '{{ filename }}'
    dest: latest
  when: not ansible_check_mode
```

or

```
- file:
    state: link
    src: '{{ filename }}'
    dest: latest
  ignore_errors: '{{ ansible_check_mode }}'
```

whichever you like more.

Comment: I'd like to point out that understanding how the module being used handles check-mode is important, be sure you understand what you're ignoring while testing a playbook. Additionally, when using `ignore_errors` a playbook run will not fail if a variable is undefined in the task, it will fail when skipping the task with `when: not ansible_check_mode`. Thus, again, it's important to understand what you're trying to test when modifying task behavior in check-mode.

Comment: Here's an updated documentation link for Ansible 4
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#skipping-tasks-or-ignoring-errors-in-check-mode

Answer (score 12):

Here is a sort of hacky solution:

```
hosts: ...
tasks:
  - command: /bin/true
    register: noop_result
  - set_fact: check_mode={{ noop_result|skipped }}

  - set_fact: filename="{{ansible_date_time.iso_8601}}"
  - file: state=touch name={{filename}}
  - file: state=link src={{filename}} dest=latest
    when: not check_mode
```

In check mode, the `command` task will be skipped so `check_mode` will be set to `true`.  When not in check mode, the task should always succeed and `check_mode` will be set to `false`.

Comment: They finally did it: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/14028
Probably will be in next ansible release.

Comment: @SelivanovPavel Woo!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same kind of situation with `unarchive`:

`unarchive` fails in check mode if the archive doesn't exist and also if the destination directory doesn't exist (both done in the steps prior to `unarchive`).
I solved this problem by setting `always_run: true` to the preparation steps so that they are also executed in check mode:

```
---

- name: create artifact directory
  file: {{ artifact_dest_dir }} state=directory
  always_run: true

- name: download artifact on the remote host
  get_url:
    url={{ artifact_url }}
    dest={{ artifact_dest_dir }}/{{ artifact_filename }}
    force=yes
  always_run: true

- name: unpack build artifact
  unarchive: src={{ artifact_dest_dir }}/{{ artifact_filename }}
             dest={{ artifact_dest_dir }}
             copy=no
```

It works in my case, but with time dependent directories, this might not be a good solution.

Comment: In my real use case, the step that creates the file is an operation that I definitely don't want to run when in check mode.

Answer (score 1):

Other options to be aware of are tags or the `--step` option.

**Tags**

```
tasks:
    - set_fact: filename="{{ansible_date_time.iso8601}}"
    - file: state=touch name={{filename}}
    - file: state=link src={{filename}} dest=latest
      tags:
        - test
```

Then the Ansible command to use would be:

`ansible-playbook example.yml --skip-tags "test" --check`

There are other examples for skipping/specifying the tasks you would like to run using tags in the [Ansible tags documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html).

**Start and Step**

Ansible also provides a nice step-by-step debugging mode with the `--step` option.

Running `ansible-playbook example.yml --step --check` will interactively take you through each task in your playbook

From the "Start and Step" section of the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_startnstep.html):

> This will cause ansible to stop on each task, and ask if it should execute that task. Say you had a task called “configure ssh”, the playbook run will stop and ask:
>
> `Perform task: configure ssh (y/n/c):`
>
> Answering “y” will execute the task, answering “n” will skip the task, and answering “c” will continue executing all the remaining tasks without asking.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28888474/3818447) already, I wanted to mention that the solution mentioned by [augurar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572431/augurar) did not work for me as I kept getting the following error: `skipped expects a dictionary`

What ended working for me was a slightly less hacky solution by passing and extra variable with the `-e` flag as follow:

```
# On the terminal
ansible-playbook [...] --check -e '{"check_mode":true}'

# In the playbook or role
when: [...] and not check_mode

# In the proper `group_vars/` file
check_mode: false
```

Let me know what you guys think!

Comment: I'm curious as to why my solution didn't work for you.  What version of Ansible are you using?  What happens if you add a `debug: var=noop_result` task before the `set_fact`?

Answer (score -1):

You probably could just set a `when: filename is defined` to all tasks. Downside is, you can not fail in normal mode if `filename` would not be defined.

```
hosts: ...
tasks:
    - set_fact: filename="{{ansible_date_time.iso_8601}}"
    - file: state=present name={{filename}}
      when: filename is defined
    - file: state=link src={{filename}} dest=latest
      when: filename is defined
```

Comment: I'm more concerned about the general question, not this specific case.

Comment: Anyway, this doesn't even work for the specific case.  The problem is that when the first file task is not executed, the second file task fails because the link target does not exist.